# Image of holomorphic function being measure zero implies constant function

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

Problem: Let $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic function, and $f(A)$ is contained in a measure zero set in $\mathbb{C}$. Prove that $f$ is constant.

Attempt at solution: The statement seems to have some connections with the open mapping theorem, but my $A$ here is not necessarily a connected open set so I cannot directly use it here. I can't seem to find a way to use the measure zero image properly. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is $A$ here? If it contains a connected open set $U$, you can apply the open mapping theorem to $f(U)$. (Also your $A$ better be connected, otherwise a function that is constant on connected components but not globally constant is a (trivial) counterxample.)

Comment: What means holomorphic in an arbitrary subset of $\Bbb C$?

Comment: This is not how the problem is stated. Please give us the complete precise statement of the problem, otherwise this question may be closed.

Comment: This is really the complete statement of the problem.

Comment: Really? Somehow I doubt it. Come on: What if $A$ is a single point?

Comment: Then take $A = [0,1]$ and $f(z) = z$. Whoops, $f(A)$ has measure $0$, but $f$ isn't constant. Unless we have some constraints on $A$, the conclusion doesn't follow.

Comment: Ok I see, then the problem is flawed no wonder I couldn't prove it... sorry for the trouble guys, I'll need to talk to my prof about this.

Comment: @zhw.: Ok one more question: if we assume $A$ is open does it yield anything more useful?

Comment: If $A$ is open, the open mapping theorem tells us that $f(A)$ has measure $0$ if and only if $f$ is constant on each connected component of $A$, since nonempty open sets have positive measure.

Comment: You don't need the open mapping : take $z_0$ where $f'(z_0) \ne 0$, it exists iff $f$ is non-constant, then $f(z) = f(z_0)+f'(z_0)(z-z_0)+o(|z-z_0|)$. Thus for $r$ small enough, the image of $\{ |z-z_0| < r\}$ is a simply connected open which looks like $\{ |z-f(z_0)| < r |f'(z_0)|\}$, which is not "of measure zero".

Comment: @reuns: very interesting, I think this is the intended solution then!

Comment: And obviously $A$ has to be connected, since if it isn't, $f$ can clearly have different values on different components without violating $\mu(f(A)) = 0$. I'm sure that $A$ is meant to be a domain.

Comment: @reuns Why is that image open? Seems to me you are using some kind of open mapping theorem